# Encoding and decoding in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say we have a string 'a\b'.
I need to encode it first, save to file, then read it from file and puck back in db.

**How to encode and decode text that has escape characters?**

```
select encode(E'a\b'::bytea, 'base64')
"YQg="
select decode('YQg=', 'base64')
"a\010"
```

After decoding I am not getting back string as it was in it's original form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using an `E''` string (escape string) and *casting* to `bytea`. The result will be a representation of that string in your current database encoding - probably UTF-8.

`E'a\b'` is the character `a` then the character represented by the escape `\b` which is ordinal `\x08`. PostgreSQL represents this string with a hex-escape when printing to the terminal because it's a non-printable character. The string is still two characters long.

```
postgres=> SELECT E'a\b';
 ?column? 
----------
 a\x08
(1 row)

postgres=> SELECT length(E'a\b');
 length 
--------
      2
(1 row)
```

The cast to `bytea` implicitly does a conversion to the current database encoding:

```
postgres=> SELECT E'a\b'::bytea;
 bytea  
--------
 \x6108
(1 row)
```

(`\x61` is the ASCII ordinal for `a` in most encodings).

Except you must be on an old PostgreSQL since you have `bytea_output = escape`, resulting in octal escape output instead:

```
postgres=> SELECT E'a\b'::bytea;
 bytea 
-------
 a\010
(1 row)
```

You need to *decode* the bytea back into a text string, e.g.

```
convert_from(decode('YQg=', 'base64'), 'utf-8')
```

... and even then the nonprintable character \b will be printed as `\x08` by `psql`.  You can verify that it is really that character inside the database using another client.

BTW, what's going on would be clearer if you instead explicitly encoded it when you stored it rather than relying on a cast to bytea:

```
encode(convert_to(E'a\b', 'utf-8'), bytea)
```

Comment: select convert_from(decode('YQg=', 'base64'), 'utf-8') does not return 'a\b', but instead 'a<and some weird character>'.

Comment: Running on version 9.1.14

Comment: @EdijsPetersons Then your database encoding is not UTF-8. Check `SELECT server_encoding;` to see.

Comment: select convert_from(decode('YQg=', 'base64'), 'utf-8') does not return 'a\b', but instead 'a\x08'

Comment: Encoding is UTF8. Just tried on postgres 9.2 and same result.

Comment: @EdijsPetersons Er, `a\x08` *is* `E'a\b'` - the hex representation of it. `E'\b'` is the nonprintable character 0x08 (oct ord 008). If you want a literal `a\b` don't use the `E''` escape-string syntax.